# I am trying to pass and array of composite type as parameter to a postgres function using c#

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Hi I am trying to pass array of composite type as parameters to a postgres function as an alternative to Tablevaluedparameters in MSSQL. However, I am not able to pass the paramters to the function. I have been using below versions
Npgsql - 7
.NET 6
Please suggest a way to map the type with db and call the procedure.
I am using below code to call the function with array of composite type but composite is not present in NpgsqlDbType.

```
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("your_connection_string"))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = new NpgsqlCommand("your_function_name", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    var compositeTypeArray = new[] { new YourCompositeType("value1"), new YourCompositeType("value2") };
    var compositeTypeArrayParameter = new NpgsqlParameter("your_parameter_name", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Composite)
    {
        Value = compositeTypeArray
    };
    command.Parameters.Add(compositeTypeArrayParameter);

    var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Consider adding the function definition, your intended result, what you've tried and in what way it's not working -- in short a [mre].

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you pass a JSON array instead since PostgreSQL is very good at processing these.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm PostgreSQL is also very good at processing composite types, any specific reason you're recommending avoiding them?

Comment: As above, @ajinkya-kulkarni you need to post a minimal repro

Comment: @ShayRojansky The only reason is that unlike specific composite types, JSON is almost generally adopted as a serialization format by most languages. So using it might help make code more portable and easier to read, test, troubleshoot etc.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Thanks for the suggestion, but can't we use composite types from c# as mentioned above or is there any other way I could map those CLR types to postgres types?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure that I can help to map those CLR types to postgres types

Comment: @Stefanov.sm composite types are simply user-defined database types which are mapped directly to .NET types; there's nothing about them that's less readable than JSON. Any driver properly supporting PostgreSQL should be able to map them. The docs for mapping composite types with Npgsql are https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html

Comment: @ShayRojansky well, I agree, and it is a matter of taste too

Comment: @ShayRojansky can we do it with EF core?

Comment: Unfortunately not - the PostgreSQL EF provider doesn't yet support composite types (https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/22) - but it indeed does support JSON :)